# Why doesn't \@ifstar work inside a caption?

Tags: macros

For some reason, the following minimal example doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testMe}{%
    test
    \@ifstar{1}{2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\testMe
\testMe*
\begin{figure}
  bla bla bla
  \caption{\testMe*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, if you uncomment the `\@ifstar` line, or don't use `\testMe` in the caption then it works. Why?

Comment: Commands defined in that way are fragile, so you need `\protect\testMe` in the moving arguments, for instance the caption text.

Comment: I see. Is there no way of checking the presence of a star such that I don't need to use `\protect` before every such use?

Comment: Yes, there are at least two ways.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Commands defined in that way are fragile, so you need `\protect\testMe` in the moving arguments, for instance the caption text.

Let's see why. The argument to `\caption` needs to be massaged a few times, in particular it gets written to the `.aux` file for possible inclusion in the list of figures (or tables).

When TeX does a `\write` operation, it expands commands “all the way”, unless instructed not to do so (which is the purpose of `\protect`). During this expansion in `\write` operations, `\@ifstar` or `\@ifnextchar` (which `\@ifstar` is defined upon) break because they need to assign a value to a scratch macro to work and this is not possible during expansion.

Thus you have three possibilities:

1. use `\protect\testMe` when in a moving argument
2. use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for defining `\testMe` (same syntax as `\newcommand`)
3. use `xparse`.

The last possibility needs a comment. If you do

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\testMe}{s}
 {test \IfBooleanTF{#1}{1}{2}}
```

you get basically the same as your `\testMe`, but automatically protected when found in moving arguments.

Comment: In fact, I used exactly the same code like your last example (with `xparse`). =) Thanks!

Comment: @egreg I have got a similar question, would you mind helping me please? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337420/why-does-redefining-contentsname-conflict-with-redefining-section-when-there-i