# Why does redefining \contentsname conflict with redefining \section when there is a \tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, starred-version, robust-commands, titlecaps

I am trying to modify the title of table of content and make every title of sections uppercase.
But strange compilation errors occurred.

The .tex file looks like the following one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{szx}
\begin{document}
    \section*{fgh}
        vbn
    \tableofcontents
    \section{zxc}
        qwe
\end{document}
```

And I have tried 3 different szx.sty file, neither of them works.

The first one uses xparse package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{szx}

\usepackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{titlecaps}

\let\@szx@oldsection\section
\newcommand{\@szx@sectionstar}[1]{\@szx@oldsection*{\titlecap{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@szx@section}[1]{\@szx@oldsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\@szx@sectionstar}{\@szx@section}}

\let\@szx@TocName\contentsname
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\centering{\@szx@TocName}}
```

The second one uses `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{szx}

\RequirePackage{titlecaps}

\let\@szx@oldsection\section
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@szx@sectionstar}[1]{\@szx@oldsection*{\titlecap{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@szx@section}[1]{\@szx@oldsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\section}{\@ifstar\@szx@sectionstar\@szx@section}

\let\@szx@TocName\contentsname
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\contentsname}{\centering{\@szx@TocName}}
```

The last one uses makerobust package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{szx}

\RequirePackage{makerobust}
\RequirePackage{titlecaps}

\let\@szx@oldsection\section
\newcommand{\@szx@sectionstar}[1]{\@szx@oldsection*{\titlecap{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@szx@section}[1]{\@szx@oldsection{\titlecap{#1}}}
\MakeRobustCommand{\@szx@sectionstar}
\MakeRobustCommand{\@szx@section}
\renewcommand{\section}{\@ifstar\@szx@sectionstar\@szx@section}
\MakeRobustCommand{\section}

\let\@szx@TocName\contentsname
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\centering{\@szx@TocName}}
\MakeRobustCommand{\contentsname}
```

The error messages were the same and looks like:

> Use of \titlecap doesn't match its definition. \tableofcontents
>
> Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. \tableofcontents
>
> Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete. \tableofcontents
>
> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \tableofcontents
>
> Undefined control sequence. \tableofcontents
>
> Illegal parameter number in definition of \the@@@string.
>   \tableofcontents
>
> Undefined control sequence. \tableofcontents
>
> Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 12.

Comment: All definitions are wrong, as they no longer allow an optional argument to `\section`. Using a formatting command in the code for `\contentsname` is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: @egreg Could you help me centering the caption of table of content while all section titles are capitalized?

Comment: @egreg Thanks, you inspired me to re-search the solutions instead of writing my own blindly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a bit more careful in doing those redefinitions.

Moreover the `\titlecap` command seems to conflict with `\centering`. In any case, adding formatting instructions to `\contentsname` is wrong. If you want a capitalized name for the contents, define it explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\latexsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {%
     \latexsection*{\titlecap{#3}}%
    }%
    {
     \IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {%
        \latexsection{\titlecap{#3}}%
       }%
       {%
        \latexsection[\titlecap{#2}]{\titlecap{#3}}%
       }%
    }%
}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\section}
  {\latexsection}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}
  {\contentsname}
  {\centering\contentsname}
  {}{}
\makeatother

%% no babel
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
%% babel
%\addto\captionsenglish{%
%  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
%}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{fgh fgh, fgh}
vbn

\section{zxc zxc, zxc}
qwe

\section[sh]{zxc zxc, zhc}
qwe

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `\patchcmd`, that is a brand new thing to me through all the searches I have done.

Answer (score 0):

With @egreg's suggestion, I searched for another way of centering the caption of table of content.

Just replace the re-definition of `\contentsname` with

`\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\hfill\@szx@TocName\hfill\hfill}`

will solve the conflict.

P.S.

To capitalize section title:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129682/101988